# I want to put the opponent's information into a new column in a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have all of the following columns in a Pandas DataFrame except for Opp_DRPM

```
    Date  Name              Team Opp DRPM Pos Opp_DRPM
    11/22 Stephen Curry     gsw  okc 1.0  1   2.2
    11/22 Russell Westbrook okc  gsw 2.2  1   1.0
```

What I would like to do is: for each date and for each player, put the amount of the DRPM in a new column "Opp_DRPM" based on the Opponent and the same position they play.

So, for example, Stephen Curry is a point guard (Position 1) and plays for GSW. GSW is playing OKC and matched up with Russell Westbrook, who is also a point guard (Position 1). I want to put Russell Westbrook's DRPM into Stephen Curry's row and vice versa.

Comment: Show your expected output

Comment: That is my expected output. I have all of the columns except Opp_DRPM, which would be a new column and looks like what I have shown above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Group by sorted Opp and Team, then transform the order.

```
df['Opp_DRPM']=df.groupby(list(map(''.join,(np.sort(df[['Opp','Team']].values,1))))).DRPM.transform(lambda x : x.iloc[::-1])
df
Out[60]: 
    Date              Name Team  Opp  DRPM  Pos  Opp_DRPM
0  11/22      StephenCurry  gsw  okc   1.0    1       2.2
1  11/22  RussellWestbrook  okc  gsw   2.2    1       1.0
```

Comment: i think it worked! i'm testing it now. Just to throw a curve ball, if I converted the Team and Opp to Integers, how would the code change?

Comment: @GilO'Brien that will be the same , you can test it

Comment: I need to include the Date and Pos as well in the group. The date is a datetime64[ns] column.

Comment: @GilO'Brien change to`df.groupby(['Date',list(map(''.join,(np.sort(df[['Opp','Team']].values,1))))]).DRPM.transform(lambda x : x.iloc[::-1])`

Comment: I edited my comment after you posted your code. i also need Pos to be in the group.

Comment: I think I got it. I just put 'Date',  'Pos'. I sanity checked it and it works! Thanks for your help!